# What's the name of the old cross country ski boots with three holes at the front?

Tags: boots, cross-country-skiing

I have old cross country skis which require those boots with a flat end with three holes which you insert into three pegs on the skis. I'm looking for the name of that style of boot in order to be able to find some on craigslist or similar websites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think those were the original 3-pin Nordic Norm bindings.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ski_binding#Cross_country:

> 75 mm (Rottefella, Nordic Norm, 3-pin) This is the original, classic system found on cross country skis, invented by Bror With. These bindings, once the standard, are no longer as popular as they were but still hold a significant share of the market for mid-weight touring setups with relatively heavy boots, as typically used for hut-to-hut touring in Norway. In this system the binding has three small pins that stick up. The toe of the boot has three holes that line up with the pins. The boot is then clamped down by a bail. Despite the decreasing use of the 3 pin "rat trap" ("rottefella" in Norwegian) binding in lighter cross country, the characteristic "duckbill" toe it uses is still assumed in the design of heavier cable bindings, and 75 mm boots are still widely available, especially for telemark technique and more rugged touring.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Is there additionnal terminology which could refer specifically to the lighter, low rising, "soft" kind? (as opposed to the heavy duty "hard-shelled" version)

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm an ATer :) I just happened to have some vague memory of that description after reading the wiki on bindings a few months ago.